# \boldsymbol is ignored in Bookdown

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown, bookdown

I am using Bookdown to publish a project I am working on. I am trying to print an equation with bold symbols inside using `\boldsymbol`. When I build the PDF, `\boldsymbol` command is ignored and the  equation in the PDF file is not bolded. For example, if I try `$\boldsymbol{x}$`, the PDF file is printed like if I wrote `$x$`.

If I use just RMarkdown without Bookdown everything works properly.

I have also tried using bm package and `\bm` but I get a compilation error.

Thanks to anyone who can help me.

**EDIT:** I add the code from `index.Rmd` file.

```
--- 
title: "boldsymbol test"
author: ""
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
documentclass: book
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    includes:
      in_header: "preamble.tex"
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: "preamble.tex"
---

This equation is bolded:

$\boldsymbol A=\boldsymbol B\boldsymbol B^T$

This other one is not:

$A= B B^T$
```

The problem is that the output in pdf is the same (the fisrt equation is not printed bolded). If you take a look to the .tex file that is generated from the .md in the render process, you can see that `\boldsymbol` command was actually printed in the equation, but then is ignored in the compilation to PDF.

This only happens when using `bookdown::pdf_book` and not if `pdf_document` is used (`pdf_document` prints the equation bolded in both PDF and .tex). The downside of using `pdf_document` is that Bookdown features are lost.

Comment: Welcome to SO, @despepite. Did you try with two slashes, i.e. `\\boldsymbol`?

Comment: Thanks @bttomio. I have tried what you say but does not work for me. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to add the problematic part of your code? It's useful to see your question with a code. Thanks.

Comment: I have just edited the question 

Answer (score 0):

I tried your minimal example and it worked fine for me. But I had another example where it failed in a similar way. Finally, I nailed down the issue in my case. I was using this option from the default book template:

```
bookdown::pdf_book:
  latex_engine: xelatex
```

My problems were solved by using instead:

```
bookdown::pdf_book:
  latex_engine: pdflatex
```

Let's see if it works for you. However, in your example you don't specify that option and I think by default it's pdflatex, so not sure it will help you.